# Redux Data Flow with React-hooks

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks

[image]

I am building a web application.

I'm trying to use `react-hooks`.

and I've almost finished it.

but, I felt that my **redux-flow** is something **weird** like the above picture.

I just wonder I am doing properly.

**MyStore.js**

```
import {handleActions} from 'redux-actions';
import produce from 'immer';

export const INPUT_DATA = 'INPUT_DATA';

const initialState = {
  id: '',
  name: '',
  email: '',
  address: '',
  gender: '',
};

export default handleActions({
  [INPUT_DATA]: (state, action) => {
    return produce(state, draft=>{
      draft = {...state, ...action.payload};
    });
  },
  ...
},initialState);
```

**FormA.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import {useDispatch} from 'react-redux';

const FormA = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [data, setData] = React.useState({id:'',name:'',email:''});
  React.useEffect(()=>{
    dispatch({type: INPUT_DATA, payload: data });
  },[data]);
  function handleChange(e,name){
    setData({...data, [name]:e.target.value});
  }

  return (
    <>
      <input type="text" value={data.id} onChange={(e)=>handleChange(e,'id')} />
      <input type="text" value={data.name} onChange={(e)=>handleChange(e,'name')} />
      <input type="text" value={data.email} onChange={(e)=>handleChange(e,'email')} />
    </>
  );
}
```

**FormB.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import {useDispatch} from 'react-redux';

const FormB = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [data, setData] = React.useState({address:'',gender:''});
  React.useEffect(()=>{
    dispatch({type: INPUT_DATA, payload: data });
  },[data]);
  function handleChange(e,name){
    setData({...data, [name]:e.target.value});
  }

  return (
    <>
      <input type="text" value={data.address} onChange={(e)=>handleChange(e,'address')} />
      <input type="text" value={data.gender} onChange={(e)=>handleChange(e,'gender')} />
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your code is following that sort of redux pattern, then it should be solid.

This would be the ideal path:

```
Component -> action -> middleware -> API -> reducer -> props -> Component
```

Seems consistent with this flow as well:

```
https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/1600/*1QERgzuzphdQz4e0fNs1CFQ.gif
```

[image]

Comment: @zynkn do you ever connect your components to the redux-store? It doesnt look like you would get updated props as is.

Comment: I am using redux-store for geting data from api-server and it would be displayed `<ListView />` component.

Comment: Sweet yeah that's expected flow then. I was just commenting on the code you provided above. :)

Comment: I mean, `<FormA />` and redux-store have same (or duplicated) states. is it okay?

Comment: Yeah, there is nothing wrong with that. The state managed by the component and state managed by the reducer can have identical data but exist as different entities. However I am concerned about your useEffect logic. As currently constructed, you are dispatching an action each time any of the input data changes via setData and handleChange. You probably would be better served using a submit handler upon completion of the form. :)

Answer (score 0):

FC ListView seems to be functional component here and you can use hooks here to manage a pseudo state by importing useState from react package.

1. Export FC ListView with connect()();
2. Import useState from react;
3. Update state using this hook.

   import { useState } from 'react';

const ListingTable = (props) => {

```
let [name, updateName] = useState('John Doe');
return (
    <div>
        <p>{name}</p>
        <button onClick={_ => updateName('Alex')}> Change Name</button>
    </div>
);};
```

You can use useState as setState here to manage state variables in your functional component.